# Using win32_NetworkAdapterSettings to query a specific NIC. C#

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi

Im trying to get tcp/ip info and physical info from a NIC card. I have queries for both (from win_32 NetworkAdapter and win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration) But i want to join them together so i can select a specific network card from a combobox and get both sets of info.

I have been told I can use win_32 NetworkAdaptersetting but Im pretty new to this stuff so I don't know how!! It must be in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace WMITest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                    "Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapter");

            foreach (ManagementObject adapter in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(adapter["Name"]);

                foreach(ManagementObject configuration in
                    adapter.GetRelated("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(configuration["Caption"]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, Now to show ho wmuch of a noob i am!!! Am I supposed to create that class then query it from my main class? :P

Comment: No, in the example I first used ManagementObjectSearcher to get all instances of Win32_NetworkAdapter. It returns a collection of ManagementObject instances that represent Win32_NetworkAdapter instances. You could use another ways to get a ManagementObject instance, but you can always use ManagementObject.GetRelated() to get an associated WMI object (in this case an instance of Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration). In any case, once you get a Win32_NetworkAdapter instance as a ManagementObject you can use GetRelated() to get associated instances.

Comment: Damn Im dumb!!! Thanks dude, i got what i wanted using 'ASSOCIATORS OF' But this seems a more elegant and flexible solution.